# R выделение подгрупп

Tags: r, статистика

Господа, направьте на путь истинный. У меня есть числовой ряд. Он явно состоит из неких подмножеств. Как мне их выделить на R ?

Например 
1
1
2
1
2
50
43
70
60
1
0.002111
0.2
0.1

Т.е. если грубо, то видно, что есть подгруппы 0-1, 1-9, 40-70

Как называется данный подход для извлечения данных и как это можносделать на R ?

Comment: Это такая одномерная кластеризация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за направление. 
Пишу простенький пример на данную тему. Использовал К-средние как наиболеепростой путь, но для моих данных вполне подходит

```
> a=c(0.1,0.1212,0.2211,10,12,164,158)
> kmeans(a,centers=3)
K-means clustering with 3 clusters of sizes 2, 2, 3

Cluster means:
         [,1]
1  11.0000000
2 161.0000000
3   0.1474333

Clustering vector:
[1] 3 3 3 1 1 2 2

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1]  2.000000000 18.000000000  0.008364887
 (between_SS / total_SS =  99.9 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss" "tot.withinss"
[6] "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"         "ifault"      
> f=kmeans(a,centers=3)
> data.frame(f$centers, f$size)
  f.centers f.size
1   4.48846      5
2 158.00000      1
3 164.00000      1
```

Comment: хотелось бы конечно получить не средние и диапазоны, мин-макс

Answer (score 0):

dist() принимает одномерные данные, только оформите их как датафрейм

```
> str(dist(data.frame(x=runif(10))))
Class 'dist'  atomic [1:45] 0.9009 0.0551 0.0668 0.0307 0.3536 ...
..- attr(*, "Size")= int 10
..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
..- attr(*, "method")= chr "Euclidean"
..- attr(*, "call")= language dist(x = data.frame(x = runif(10)))
>
```